# regex for find cmd to output all files with an 'e' in them but not at start/end of name

Tags: linux, bash, expression

I need a find command to output all filenames in a certain directory that contain an 'e' but the 'e' must not be at the start/end of the file name.

```sh
$ ls .
emil eva extreme let yes
```

The find command I am looking for should only output `let` and `yes`, not the other names.

Things I have tried so far:

```sh
find dir -name "*e*
find dir -name "^e$"
find dir -name "[a-z]e[a-z]"
```

Similar questions I cannot figure out:

list all files that:

- begin with a,z or y
- do not begin with x,z or y
- consist of only one char
- consist of only two chars
- consist of only two OR three chars

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From the documentation «... **-name** […] matches shell style pattern. The metacharacters ('*', '?', and '[]') match a '.' at the start of the base name ...»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to understand, enter the command

```
man find
```

I think you can easily solve the others and if not, ask them in another question.
solution for case with letters "e":

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex  '^\./[^e].*e.*[^e]$'
```

explanation:

```
find. looks in the current directory
-maxdepth 1 does not go into subdirectories
-type f only displays files
-regextype sed sets the type of regular expressions to those for sed
-regex '^\./[^e].*e.*[^e]$'   the regular expression

^ the beginning of the sequence
\. literal dot
/ literal '/'
[^e] character not being the letter e
.* any number of any characters
e literal sign e
$ end of the sequence
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The regex you provided works. Is there a way to specify this command in a way that would allow me to use it to search two directories at once? I changed to he home dir and tried replacing the '.' that specifies the current directory with the absolute paths for the directories I want to search but my output is nil. 

Thanks very much.

Comment: if you provide other catalogs than. after find you must also change the beginning of the regular expression to match them: instead of ^\. use ^.* and it should work as far as I understood correctly.

Comment: Can't find somewhere the regextype sed but it work. You can also try find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '[^e]*e*[^e]'

Comment: @ctac_ Your RE wouldn't allow multiple e in the middle (mixed with other chars) and require the 2nd last char to be an e.

Comment: @LotPings, sorry, I don't understand. Give a example of filename which don't catch.

Comment: @ctac_`test` has no e at begin/end, one in between and your RE wouldn't catch it. In an RE the asterisk is a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), meaning any number of the previous, not a wildcard.

Comment: You can use -name but -name uses the "shell paterns", it's embarrassing because it depends on the type (and version) of the shell and may require escape characters -regex by default uses the syntax "emacs patterns", the safest way to use one type of regular expression everywhere. I use sed regex.

Comment: @LotPings The quote prevent the expansion from the shell so * means matches any zero or more characters. Have you a link for -regextype sed ,I can't find it and sed can use BRE and ERE .

Comment: For example, sed regexp:
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html
You can read about sed for example under:
http://sed.sourceforge.net/#docs